# Error after Shopware update from 6.2.2 to 6.2.3

Tags: shopware

I have a monorepo with `shopware/development`, `shopware/platform` and `custom/plugins` in it.
Application works on Docker and shows current version as `v9999999 Developer Version`.
Demo data as products, properties and categories were deleted and new set was imported.

I was trying to update `shopware/platform`. My steps:

1. Download code form https://github.com/shopware/platform/releases/tag/v6.2.3
2. Copy it to 'platform' folder
3. Run commands in container `muenkel_app_server_1`

```
composer install
bin/console database:migrate --all
bin/console theme:refresh
bin/console cache:clear
```

Front shows

```
Notice: Undefined index: structs
in platform/src/Core/Framework/DataAbstractionLayer/FieldSerializer/ListingPriceFieldSerializer.php (line 30)
     
      return new ListingPriceCollection();        
    }  
       
    $value = json_decode((string) $value, true);  
      
    return new ListingPriceCollection(unserialize($value['structs']));    
  }
}
```

Backend doesn't load product list

`38 b67864  POST    xhr 500 http://muenkel.local.de/api/v2/search/product`

What did I miss in update process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out what the cause is yet, but a temporary workaround is to add this on line 30 in `ListingPriceFieldSerializer.php`;

```
if (!isset($value['structs'])) {
    $value['structs'] = 'a:0:{}';
}
```

Update; it is fixed in version 6.3.0.0, see commit here; https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/20a4e656d9dcf54ff2180d1e28baac1495b30173

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Delete vendor folder
2. Run command `composer install`

Comment: Additional to that I had to delete composer.lock and after make symlink for `vendor/shopware/platform`